# Not able to add images to unordered list items in columns

Tags: jquery, html, css, list, html-lists

I made these two work standalone  but I am not able to make them work together and i just can't figure out why.

I need to achieve 2 things on a page : 
 - Have unordered list of items in 3 colums ( there are a lot of list items to be listed)
 - Have a tick box in front of every list item.

I managed to achieve the column view and I managed to achieve the icon in front of each list item. But i cannot make them work together.

I am testing on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/glee/Fa722/

Here's the HTML

```
 <div class="licol">    
 <ul id="ul.TickList">
 <li>apples</li>
 <li>pears</li>
 <li>bananas</li>
 <li>grapes</li>
 </ul></div>
 <div class="licol">    
 <ul>
 <li>cheese</li>
 <li>milk</li>
 <li>cookies</li>
 <li>oreos</li>
 </ul></div>
 <div class="licol">    
 <ul>
 <li>apricot</li>
 <li>cherries</li>
 <li>oranges</li>
 <li>pineapple</li>
 </ul></div>
```

And the CSS.

```
ul.TickList {
   list-style-image:url(http://simplyelegant.us.tempcloudsite.com/images/icons/small_icons/16px-bluecheck-icon.png);
      width: 700px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.licol {
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: your css call for `ul.TickList` should be `#ul.TickList`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your html should only be this:

```
<ul id="TickList">
<!-- Content -->
</ul>
```

Your css call should be:

```
#TickList li {
position: relative;
left: 20px;
list-style-type:circle;
list-style-image:url('http://simplyelegant.us.tempcloudsite.com/images/icons/small_icons/16px-bluecheck-icon.png');
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. Am I calling it correctly in HTML with <ul id="#ul.TickList"> ?

Comment: I didn't even see that, look at the edit here in a few. Also, you should be pointing it toward the li elements.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work either. 
Try it out over here please http://jsfiddle.net/glee/Fa722/

Comment: I got the fiddle working. The code is above and edited. Also, here's the fiddle again: http://jsfiddle.net/glee/Fa722/